# KeyError: 0 Python - Can't find the issue in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I'm making a flappy Bird clone for a college project and keep running into this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\computer science\ROCKETGAME\RocketGame.py", line 215, in <module>
    menuscreen()
  File "E:\computer science\ROCKETGAME\RocketGame.py", line 46, in menuscreen
    maingame()
  File "E:\computer science\ROCKETGAME\RocketGame.py", line 131, in maingame
    if 0<upperObs[0]['x']<5:
KeyError: 0
```

Here is the line being referenced by the error message:

```
if 0<upperObs[0]['x']<5:
```

I will post the whole code up to the point of the error as this will likely help with the solution of the issue.

(Sorry it is a lot, I've only learnt python through school and made extremely rudimentary projects, nothing of this scale, and I am very new to StackOverflow so don't know how this works fully yet)

I am following an online tutorial but have had several issues with it that I have had to fix myself, and the tutorial does not cover any of the error messages. I have had several errors during development that I have had to debunk myself without knowing about StackOverflow.

```
import random
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#global var
fps = 32
scrwid = 289 #screen width
scrhi = 511 #screen height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scrwid, scrhi)) #make game window to mimick mobile size
GROUNDY = scrhi * 0.8 #declare ground variable
game_sprites = {}
game_sounds = {}
PLAYER = 'resources\SPRITES\\Rocket1.png' #player sprite
BACKGROUND = 'resources\SPRITES\\PygameStage.png' #background sprite
OBSTACLE = 'resources\SPRITES\\object1.png' #obstaclesprite

def menuscreen(): #menu screen function
    
    playerx = int(scrwid/5)
    playery = int(scrhi - game_sprites['player'].get_height())/2
    menux = int(scrwid - game_sprites['menuscreen'].get_width())/2
    menuy = int(scrhi * 0.13)
    basex = 0

    #draw rectangle for play button
    playbutton = pygame.Rect(108,222,68,65)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit() #quit game if player has a certain input

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_SPACE or event.key == K_UP):
                return

            pygame.mouse.set_cursor(pygame.SYSTEM_CURSOR_ARROW)
            if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] > playbutton[0] and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < playbutton[0] + playbutton[2]:
                if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] > playbutton[1] and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < playbutton[1] + playbutton[3]:
                    pygame.mouse.set_cursor(pygame.SYSTEM_CURSOR_HAND)

            if playbutton.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                    maingame()


            else:
                screen.blit(game_sprites['background'],(0,0))
                screen.blit(game_sprites['player'],(playerx,playery))
                screen.blit(game_sprites['menuscreen'],(menux,menuy))
                screen.blit(game_sprites['base'],(basex,GROUNDY))
                pygame.display.update()
                FPSCLOCK.tick(fps)


                
def maingame():
    score = 0
    playerx = int(scrwid/5)
    playery = int(scrhi/2)
    basex = 0

#creating upper and lower obstacles
    newObs1 = getRandomObstacle()
    newObs2 = getRandomObstacle()

    #upper obs list
    upperObs = [
        {'x':scrwid + 200,'y':newObs1[0]['y']},
        {'x':scrwid + 200 + (scrwid/2),'y':newObs2[0]['y']}
    ]

    #lower obs list
    lowerObs = [
        {'x':scrwid + 200,'y':newObs1[1]['y']},
        {'x':scrwid + 200 + (scrwid/2),'y':newObs2[1]['y']}
    ]

    obsVelX = -4 #object velocity x
    PlayerVelY = -9 
    PlayerMaxVelY = 10 #Player's maximum Y velocity
    PlayerMinVely = -8 #Player's minimum Y velocity
    PlayerAccY = 1 

    PlayerJumpAccv = -8 #velocity while flying up (Jumping)
    PlayerJumped = False

    while True:
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_SPACE or event.key == K_UP or event.key == 'w'):
                if playery > 0:
                    PlayerVelY = PlayerJumpAccv
                    PlayerJumped = True


        #check player score
        playerMidPosition = playerx + game_sprites['player'].get_width()/2
        for obstacle in upperObs:
            obsMidPosition = obstacle['x'] + game_sprites['obstacle'][0].get_width()/2
            if obsMidPosition <= playerMidPosition < obsMidPosition + 4:
                score += 1
                print("Your score is {score}")

                

        if PlayerVelY < PlayerMaxVelY and not PlayerJumped:
            PlayerVelY += PlayerAccY

        if PlayerJumped: #Makes it so the player cannot go below the ground when it hits it.
            PlayerJumped = False
        playerheight = game_sprites['player'].get_height()
        playery = playery + min(PlayerVelY, GROUNDY - playery - playerheight)



        #move obstacles to the left of the screen
        for upperObs, lowerObs in zip(upperObs, lowerObs):
            upperObs['x'] += obsVelX
            lowerObs['x'] += obsVelX


        #create new obstacle when needed
            if 0<upperObs[0]['x']<5:
                newObs = getRandomObstacle()
                upperObs.append(newObs[0])
                lowerObs.append(newObs[1])

        #when an obstacle is off screen destroy it
            if upperObs[0]['x']< -game_sprites['obstacle'][0].get_width():
                upperObs.pop(0)
                lowerObs.pop(0)
```

I have tried googling the answer, and that is where I discovered a similar thread on here discussing a similar issue. However, when I tried implementing these solutions they also did not work, so I changed the code back to how it originally was for the sake of this post.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `for upperObs, lowerObs in zip(upperObs, lowerObs)` redefines `upperObs` to be a member not the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet bellow overwrites the global state `upperObs` with a local state which should be used only in these three lines.

```
        #move obstacles to the left of the screen
        for upperObs, lowerObs in zip(upperObs, lowerObs):
            upperObs['x'] += obsVelX
            lowerObs['x'] += obsVelX
```

Just rename the variable used in the `for` so the global one is not overwriten:

```
        #move obstacles to the left of the screen
        for upper_state, lower_state in zip(upperObs, lowerObs):
            upper_state['x'] += obsVelX
            lower_state['x'] += obsVelX
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. After testing this solution it has fixed the error, and made me realise that I may need to go back and double check all of my local and global variables to make sure they do not conflict. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
    if 0<upperObs[0]['x']<5:
KeyError: 0
```

Means: I tried to access the 0-th element of `upperObs` but found nothing. The problem is most probably coming from:

```
        if upperObs[0]['x']< -game_sprites['obstacle'][0].get_width():
            upperObs.pop(0)
            lowerObs.pop(0)
```

Where you remove the items from the object. A fix can be to make sure that at least one item is always in the object at all times, so you can access it, or handle the case where no object is found with a `try` `except` block